# Jackson deserialize LocalDateTime

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, date-format, jackson-databind

I have a time field value like below  :

```
2020-10-01T15:30:27.4394205+03:00
```

I can't figure it out how to represent as date Format.

i need to deserialize it to LocalDateTime field.

I have tried like this;

```
   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

but it doesn't work. How can i deserialize it?
I am using spring boot by the way. And this value coming to rest controller request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the pattern as `pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

Your date-time string is already in the format specified by [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) which is the default format used by [`OffsetDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-10-01T15:30:27.4394205+03:00";

        // Parse the date-time string into OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // LocalDateTime from OffsetDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-01T15:30:27.439420500+03:00
2020-10-01T15:30:27.439420500
```

Comment: i recognize from  your answer that i will lost the zone/offset if i use LocalDateTime so i have decided to use OffsetDateTime type, so it always deserialize it regarding UTC, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX")
private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

Comment: thanks, i can deserialize by this way but i recognize that i will lost the timezone. so i have decided to use OffsetDateTime.

Comment: Better to convert UTC, when you need to display, you can calculate local datetime

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom deserializer for it:

```
@Log4j2
public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

 public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
    this(null);
}
    private CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer(Class<LocalDateTime> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.debug("Error while parsing date: {} ", date, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot Parse Date");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, use the deserializer:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
 @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
 private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

Similarly, if you need to serialize it, write a custom serializer too.